# Open HTTPS with urllib2 python

Tags: python, urllib2

I am trying to connect to a https page, but it fails every time. I assume it might have something to do with the proxy that I have setup.

```
proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': 'http://username:password@proxy'})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
```

And then I try and open the page

```
page = urllib2.urlopen('https://sunflowerrealtors.com/category/market-stats/').read()
```

But this fails, so is there a way to get to https pages with what I have setup, or do I need some other module to get this to work?